# MvvmCross Bindable MonoTouch.Dialog RadioElement

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, monotouch.dialog

I am attempting to create a bindable RadioElement to use in a MonoTouch.Dialog implementation in MvvmCross, and following the pattern in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/DialogExamples/DialogExamples.Touch/BindableElements (as suggested in [MvvmCross Monotouch.Dialog binding data to a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719721/mvvmcross-monotouch-dialog-binding-data-to-a-table)), I created the following class:

```
public class MvxBindableRadioElement : RadioElement, IBindableElement
{
    public IMvxBindingContext BindingContext { get; set; }

    public MvxBindableRadioElement ()
    {
        this.CreateBindingContext();

        this.DelayBind(() => {
            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MvxBindableRadioElement, PropertyCategory>();
            set.Bind().For(me => me.Caption).To(p => p.Id);
            set.Bind().For(me => me.Value).To(p => p.Value);
            set.Apply();
        });
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing) {
            BindingContext.ClearAllBindings();
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    public virtual object DataContext
    {
        get { return BindingContext.DataContext; }
        set { BindingContext.DataContext = value; }
    }
}
```

`PropertyCategory` is a basic Model:

```
public class PropertyCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

This is used as follows:

```
new Section {
    new RootElement ("Category", new RadioGroup ()) {
        new BindableSection<MvxBindableRadioElement> ().Bind(bindings, e => e.ItemsSource, vm => vm.PropertyCategories)
    }.Bind (bindings, e => e.RadioSelected, vm => vm.PropertyCategory) as Element
}
```

where `BindableSection` is taken from the MvvmCross repo mentioned above.

Debugging I am able to verify that the `newElements` variable of `MvxBindableSection` is correctly populated with `MvxBindableRadioElement`s, but the following error occurs when the `TableView.ReloadData()` line is executed:

```
MvxBind:Error: 12.12 Problem seen during binding execution for binding ItemsSource for PropertyCategories - problem TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0005c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:238 
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MethodBase.cs:114 
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding.SetValueImpl (System.Object target, System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxConvertingTargetBinding.SetValue (System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding.UpdateTargetFromSource (System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
InnerException was NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at <redacted>.iOS.Views.MvxBindableSection`1[<redacted>.Views.MvxBindableRadioElement].NotifyDataSetChanged () [0x000b9] in <redacted>/MonoTouch.Dialog/MvxBindableSection.cs:87 
at <redacted>.iOS.Views.MvxBindableSection`1[<redacted>.Views.MvxBindableRadioElement].SetItemsSource (IEnumerable value) [0x00094] in <redacted>/MonoTouch.Dialog/MvxBindableSection.cs:56 
at <redacted>.iOS.Views.MvxBindableSection`1[<redacted>.Views.MvxBindableRadioElement].set_ItemsSource (IEnumerable value) [0x00003] in <redacted>/MonoTouch.Dialog/MvxBindableSection.cs:30 
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00044] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:230
```

Troubleshooting this, I replaced the `MvxBindableRadioElement` with `CustomStringElement` from the MvvmCross repo mentioned above:

```
new MvxBindableSection<CustomStringElement>().Bind(bindings, element => element.ItemsSource, vm => vm.PropertyCategories)
```

This works like a charm. Why does the `CustomStringElement` work, but not the`MvxBindableRadioElement`? Do I have to create a bindable `RadioGroup` that wraps the `MvxBindableRadioElement`s?

EDIT:

Here is the Inner Exception (NullReferenceException):

```
at CrossUI.Touch.Dialog.Elements.RadioElement.SubscribeToRoot () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at CrossUI.Touch.Dialog.Elements.RadioElement.GetCellImpl (MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView tv) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at CrossUI.Touch.Dialog.Elements.Element.GetCell (MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView tv) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at CrossUI.Touch.Dialog.DialogViewController+Source.GetCell (MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38 
at PGPCapture.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in <redacted>/Main.cs:21
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so the issue was with the implementation of `BindableSection` (taken from [MvvmCross-Tutorials / DialogExamples](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/DialogExamples/DialogExamples.Touch/BindableElements/BindableSection.cs)):
the `Section` element's `Parent` is not set (i.e. is `null`) unless you add the elements using `AddAll()`. This issue actually occurs in the bowels of MT.Dialog itself.

The updated `MvxBindableSection` is available [here](https://gist.github.com/mrtnkrstn/a8664948f280accf2e85).